# Are all symmetric non-singular matrices positive semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are all symmetric non-singular matrices positive semi-definite? Or are they  positive definite, or could they be any thing?

Comment: No, take $-I$. This is symmetric, non singular, but far from positive definite. Take $\operatorname{diag} (1,-1)$ for a better example, which is not definite at all.

Comment: A definite example of a non-definite matrix!

Comment: Symmetric matrices correspond to quadratic forms, which are certainly not all positive (semi-)definite.